# Assembly binding failure for all old Microsoft.SharePoint (version 12.0.0.0) dlls

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, iis, gac, assembly-references

My SharePoint 2010 dev box seems to have gone crazy today. I started to get an error when using U2U's CAML builder and trying to connect to a site using the Object Model.

The error message is as follows -

System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version 12.0.0.0' etc

I turned on Assembly Binding logging and used the Fusion viewer to see what was going on - here is an excerpt from one of the logs -

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = IDDEV\spmysitesapppool
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mysites2010.iddev.local\bin
LOG: Dynamic Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ba17ee6
LOG: Cache Base = C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\4ba17ee6
LOG: AppName = c9766a3a

## Calling assembly : (Unknown).

LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\VirtualDirectories\mysites2010.iddev.local\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c
LOG: GAC Lookup was unsuccessful.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4ba17ee6/c9766a3a/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4ba17ee6/c9766a3a/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/bin/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/bin/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/_app_bin/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/_app_bin/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4ba17ee6/c9766a3a/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/4ba17ee6/c9766a3a/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/bin/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/bin/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/_app_bin/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/wss/VirtualDirectories/mysites2010.iddev.local/_app_bin/Microsoft.SharePoint/Microsoft.SharePoint.EXE.
LOG: All probing URLs attempted and failed.

As far as I'm aware SharePoint uses policy files in the GAC to redirect requests to v12 dlls to the new v14. I have checked in the GAC and those policy files seem to exist and are in tact.

It seems as though it is not reading the policy file correctly.

I have checked and tried everything I can think of - IISRESET, restarting box, deleting temp files etc.

The only thing I can guess is that a windows update has come along and broken it - I have updates enabled on my VM (a bad idea I know!).

Can anyone shed any light on this?? It's driving me mad!!

Cheers

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Check that assembly binding redirects from v.12 to v.14 are present in web.config. Thats what SharePoint uses to check what assembly to load.

Comment: Thanks Anders checked the web.config against another SharePoint box that is working and the binding redirects are identical - any more ideas?

Comment: I seem to remember that U2U CAML editor has a config file you need to edit where you insert version 14 instead of 12.

Comment: It does have a config file but there are no references in there to the 12 dll. It works fine straight out of the download on my other boxes. Decided to trash the box now anyhow - something has borked it so going to rebuild with SP1 only and no CU's!

Comment: ok. you might want to go with June refresh, but else I agree on the CU's are messing more up than they are fixing :-S